# How can I implement friction to movement of a object in a game

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics

below is the code that I'm using for movement of a object:

```
let XX = 0
let YY = 0
let maxSpeed = 100;

if(keyDown.w) {
    XX += Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*moveSpeed;
    YY += -Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*moveSpeed;
}
```

I'm trying to implement friction in it when object starts moving. like when *key is down*, speed starts to going up and it takes *n* seconds until it reaches the `maxSpeed`.
How can I Do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you need not friction but acceleration. Here is constant acceleration due to constan motor power:

```
let XX = 0
let YY = 0
let moveSpeed = 0;
let Accel = 2;
let maxSpeed = 100;

if(keyDown.w) {
    moveSpeed = Math.min(maxSpeed, moveSpeed + Accel);
    XX += Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*moveSpeed;
    YY += -Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*moveSpeed;
}
```

Comment: umm what you mean by `Max()`?

Comment: function that chossem maximal value from two arguments. Perhaps `math.max` in js. Also I corrected initial value of movespeed

Comment: And why did you use reversed functions: cos for x and -sin for y? Is your coordinate system rotated?

Comment: yes it actually is. but your code It doesn't really work and I can't see how that could work! well `Math.max` just will return *100*. well 100>0+2. it wouldn't work if you change those numbers to what ever thought

Comment: My mistake- to limit speed, one need `Math.min`